What is $\mathscr{F}(-P)$ in Goss´ Basic structures of function fields?
I´m studying Goss´ book "Basic structures of function field arithmetic" , chapter 6 about Shtukas, page 183. However, he uses a expression $\mathscr{F}(-P)$, where $\mathscr{F}$ is a torsion-free coherent $O_X$-module on $X$, a reduced and irreducible complete curve tensor a field, and P a divisor of $X$.
What does the notation $\mathscr{F}(-P)$ means?
Thanks a lot.

@Shrugs thanks for the answer. The ideal sheaf associated to $P$ is related anyhow with the sheaf $\mathscr{O}_X(-P)$? Sorry if it is obvious, but I´m a novice at this.

@Shrugs, What $O_P$ stands for?

@Shrugs the structure sheaf of the point is the same of the skyscraper sheaf?
